# TypeError: Cannot read property 'twoArgumentPooler' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-web

Recently we have upgraded the `react-native-web` package to latest version `0.17.0` From that time we are getting the issue `TypeError: Cannot read property 'twoArgumentPooler' of undefined` while running `yarn test`

[image]

To analyse this issue, gone through the code which is implemented by our developers but we didn't have anything like `twoArgumentPooler` but it's available in `react-native-web` package in the path

```
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-web/dist/cjs/exports/Touchable/BoundingDimensions.js:19:46)
```

How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your jest config file? I had a similar issue and it turned out that I was (manually) setting up the `moduleNameMapper` incorrectly. I had the following:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'react-native': 'react-native-web',
  },
```

which, upon running the tests, effectively invalidated an import on line 10 inside `react-native-web/dist/exports/Touchable/BoundingDimensions.js` (the file mentioned in your stacktrace) and surely a lot of other imports.

This

```js
import PooledClass from '../../vendor/react-native/PooledClass';
var twoArgumentPooler = PooledClass.twoArgumentPooler;
```

turned into this (notice the changed and incorrect path)

```js
import PooledClass from '../../vendor/react-native-web/PooledClass';
var twoArgumentPooler = PooledClass.twoArgumentPooler;
```

This ultimately resulted in the exact same error as you got, and was resolved by *correctly* defining the remapper entry like this:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
  },
```

Hope it helps! If nothing else, perhaps this will help someone in the future!